# Por qué no se puede retornar un <List<Directory>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en flutter y estaba practicando con un ejemplo, pero me sale el siguiente error.
Error:

```
Un valor de tipo 'Future<List<Directory>?>' no puede ser devuelto desde el método '_getExternalStoragePath' porque tiene un tipo de retorno 'Future<List<Directory>>

   Future <List<Directory>> _getExternalStoragePath() async{

   return p.getExternalStorageDirectories(type: p.StorageDirectory.documents);
   
    
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error te lo genera por que tu función `p.getExternalStorageDirectories` te regresa `List<Directory>?`, que indica que puede ser un valor nulo, [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety). Y tu función solo regresa un `List<Directory>`.

En este caso puedes hacer dos cosas.

- Igualar para que tu función regrese el mismo null safety.

```dart
    Future <List<Directory>?> _getExternalStoragePath() async{
        return p.getExternalStorageDirectories(type: p.StorageDirectory.documents);
    }
```

y cuando consultes tu información, validar que tu resultado no sea null.

- Esperar el resultado, almacenarlo en una variable y regresar el valor o un array vacío.

```dart
    Future <List<Directory>> _getExternalStoragePath() async{
        var listado= await p.getExternalStorageDirectories(type: p.StorageDirectory.documents);
        return listado ?? [];
    }
```